# IKE2 VPN with certificate?

Tags: windows, vpn, windows-11, certificate

I'm trying to create an IKE2 VPN connection on Windows11 **with certificate**.

### Trial #1:

I was imported the certificate into *Current User*'s location:

[image]

With this method, I got a plain error during connection:

[image]

### Trial #2:

Now I used *Local Machine*, connection still runs onto the same error.

### Trial #3:

Keeping the certificate in *Local Machine*'s store, and changed VPN connection's property:

[image]

Now it **works** finally.

### Problem:

I have this certificate in the Machine's store:

[image]

Unfortunately, I have to import another certificate here to connect to another VPN server. They provided the same *subject*:

[image]

I added the second VPN server connection, but now exactly one connection can work: whichever Windows finds first in this certificate store. I think ordered by creation time DESC.

To make things clear: I do **not** want to connect to two servers at the same time.

I want to be able to connect to any of the two VPN servers but only to one at a time.

I can only achieve this now with removing certificate from the store and import it before connecting to the certain server. It's very annoying.

Comment: Have you tried searching Microsoft Docs/Microsoft Learn _(Windows' man pages - it's "Learn" now)_? IPsec VPNs are outdated so I can't help there _(I'm assuming this is a corporate VPN, but if it's not and you control the server, Wireguard and OpenVPN provide the fastest, most efficient VPNs and don't have this certificate issue)_. IPsec uses SSL certs same as OpenVPN, and this would be solved on OpenVPN by modifying the client config file to use a specific value from within the client SSL cert to differentiate it from the other, such as the Common Name [CN] since CN's are supposed to be unique

Comment: CNs are unique and I prefer what Windows offers by default :)

Comment: There should be a way to manually specify how to differentiate a certificate with IPsec.

Comment: There should be yes. So how can I manually specify? Maybe with some 'clever' registry hack?

Comment: Please verify CNs are unique, as per the screenshot, they're not _(Issued To column is the CN)_, and this is likely the issue. CNs need to be unique and two certs shouldn't share the same CN when issued by the same CA/ICA, as it allows the certs, and therefore VPN tiunnel, to be exploited _(IKE2 VPN and config are operating as intended)_

Comment: If CN is my common name, then true, they are not unique. I was asked to provide my CN when I requested the certificate, and I don't want to revoke these. On Android (a phone!!!) can perfectly distinguish between these two certificates for two separate VPN connections. How can I achieve the same with windows (computer!!)?

Comment: Not a clue, certs aren't supposed to have the same common name when issued by the same ICA or CA. It's usually best to adhere to best practices instead of trying to make something obscure work.